# Cloning the `D:` disk: how do I recognize the right `if=/dev/`?

Tags: hard-drive, dd, clone, cloning

Last time when I cloned my data HDD the task was easy. I had 4TB source and 8TB target.
Now it is worse: I have two 8TB disks. My question is obvious: how do I recognize from `lsblk`
the right paths to `if=/dev` and `of=/dev` so that I do not destroy my disk with wrong target and wrong source switched in `if` and `of` parameters to `dd` ??

**EDIT**

I'm running `ubuntu 20.10 desktop` from an USB stick Kingston Traveller.

**EDIT 2**

In fact the situation is for the time being hypothetical . I haven't
now the second 8TB disk with me, I just wanted to know how to cope with it once I have it.
Last, but not least I think that it is not a good idea to plug and unplug
the empty disk while the system is up to recognize which I can safely delete,
i.e. which should be the argument of `of=`.

Comment: @user68186 Please see my edit.

Comment: Hypothetically speaking, if you buy a new 8TB disk, it will not be formatted. `lsblk` should show you that. Then you will know which drive is old and which is new.

Comment: You can always just mount the partition in question and look at the contents to decide.

Comment: When booted from Live disk open Gnome-Disks. It will tell you what is what.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron How do I run `Gnome-Disks` and how do I recognize from it `what is what` ??

Comment: from Terminal, type `gnome-disks`. in the left column select the disk you want to know about. Information about the disk and partitions will be shown on the right.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these to see details, there are others also:

```
sudo lshw -class disk
udisksctl status
```

But dd is about the worst way to copy a 8TB drive. dd aka Disk Destroyer copies all the blank/unallocated space, so very slow.

Also you then cannot mount both drives at same time, as you have duplicated UUIDs & GUIDs which is not allowed. Or if you do force a mount, you may copy some data to one drive one time & some to the other next time, getting them out of sync.

Better to gpt partition and reinstall  and use rsync to copy data. Or other image copy tools like clonezilla.